# Find sum of max integer in array with least space complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

I am new to programming and trying to learn by exploring. I was looking for a solution to find sum of maximum time repeating integer in an array with best space complexity. Suppose we have [1, 2, 3, 3] the result should be 6 with least space complexity, say O(n).

I came up with a solution but not sure about the complexity. Need some help to understand if below mentioned code has least complexity or it could be better(definitely!). Sorry if I made any mistake and thanks in advance.

```
public static int maxDuplicateSumSpaceBased(int[] a)
{
  int maxRepCount = 1, tempCount;
  int maxRepNum = a[0];
  int temp = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < (a.length - 1); i++)
  {
    temp = a[i];
    tempCount = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++)
    {
      if (temp == a[j])
        tempCount++;
    }
    if (tempCount > maxRepCount)
    {
        maxRepNum = temp;
      maxRepCount = tempCount;
    }
  }
  return maxRepNum * maxRepCount;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, what I mean is program should have as low memory consumption as possible. Hope it makes it clear, thanks

Comment: Your algorithm is good from a space complexity point of view as it only uses a few primitive variables. Its time complexity is O(n^2) when O(n) is possible.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I understand about improving time complexity by removing double loop, here I am more concerned about space complexity. What could be the space complexity of above program, if you can guide please.

Comment: Ok well that's about as good as you can get. There's no need for temp as you can just use a[i]. But a few ints is basically nothing. Ignoring the input array the extra space complexity is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the space of the input is usually not counted in the O notation so your program has a spatial complexity of O(6)=O(c)=O(1). c is a constant. In fact you always use 6 variables. If the amount of space used is dependent on the input given the situation is different but it's not your case because regardless of the length of you input you use always 6 variables.

If you want to count the input as occupied space (sometimes it's done) your space complexity would be O(6+n)=O(n) assuming that n is the length of the input.

It's impossible to do better as you can easly prove:
You can't have less memory occupied than the input (or you must memorize all the input). Since the input is the only thing that's not a constant you have that the maximum space used is the one needed to store the input that is n.

Answer (score 1):

The space complexity<sup>1</sup> of your solution is `O(1)`.  You can't get better than that.

The time complexity of your solution is `O(N^2)`.  You can improve on that in a couple of ways:

- If you can modify `a`, then you can sort it { time `O(NlogN)`, space`O(1)` } then find / count the most frequent value { `O(N)` , `O(1)` }.  Overall complexity is { `O(NlogN)`, `O(1)`}.
- If you cannot modify `a`, then copy it { `O(N)` / `O(N)` } and then proceed as above.  Overall complexity is { `O(NlogN)`, `O(N)` }.
- If the range of the numbers (M) is less than the number of numbers, then you can use a bucket sort.  Overall complexity is { `O(N)`, `O(M)` }.
- You can get better time complexity overall using a HashMap.  The overall complexity of that will be { `O(N)` on average, `O(N)`} ... with significantly larger constants of proportionality.  (Unfortunately, the worst case time complexity will be `O(NlogN)` or `O(N^2)` depending on the hash map implementation.  It occurs when all of the keys collide.  That is impossible for `Integer` keys and `HashMap`, but possible for `Long` keys.)

---

<sup>1 - I am referring to space *in addition* to the space occupied by the input array.  Obviously, the space used for the input array cannot be optimized.  It is a given.</sup>

Comment: the input is an array of integer, with some effort you can manage to solve the problem in O(n) without modifing a with a properly edited integer sort

Comment: @JoulinRouge - Really?  Please explain (in an Answer)

Comment: Nope, i wrote "with some effort" :)

Answer (score 0):

I have understand your problem.. Now there could be a solution there are n integers and all integers k [1-n]. Then to find maxrepeatnumber takes O(n) time.

```
  public static int maxDuplicateSumSpaceBased(int[] a)
{
  int maxRepCount = 1, tempCount;
  int k=a.length();
  for (int i = 0; i <k; i++)
  {
        a[a[i]%k]+=k;
  }
    int maxRepnumber=0,temp=a[0];
    for (int j = 1; j < k; j++)
    {
      if (temp < a[j])
        {
           temp=a[j];
           maxRepnumber=j;
        }
    }

  }
  return maxRepNum;
}

Then you sum all that number and it take O(n)and O(1) space.
```